# Adding device to OPC-UA IoT Agent trough REST API call

Tags: node.js, rest, fiware, opc-ua, opc

I'm struggling trying to add a device via API call.
If I start the docker container with the `docker-compse.yml`, I'm able to load a device to the local OPC-UA server, with the following REST API call.

> `curl http://localhost:4001/iot/devices -H "fiware-service: opcua_car" -H "fiware-servicepath: /demo" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @testCommands/add_device_NGSIv2.json`

But, if I start the docker container with the `docker-compse-external-server.yml`, which instead of the `iotagent4fiware/iotagent-opcua:latest` uses the `iotagent4fiware/iotagent-opcua:1.3.4`, and I use the same API call, I get the following error:

> `{"name":"WRONG_SYNTAX","message":"Wrong syntax in request: Errors found validating request."}`

From the Docker log:

```
"op":"IoTAgentNGSI.RestUtils","time":"2022-05-12T19:47:59.467Z","lvl":"DEBUG","msg":"Errors found validating request: {
    "valid":false,"errors": [
        {"attribute":"pattern","property":"devices.0.commands.1.object_id","expected":"^([^<>();'="]+)+$","actual":"ns=3;s=Accelerate","message":"invalid input"},
        {"attribute":"pattern","property":"devices.0.commands.0.object_id","expected":"^([^<>();'="]+)+$","actual":"ns=3;s=Stop","message":"invalid input"},
        {"attribute":"pattern","property":"devices.0.attributes.4.object_id","expected":"^([^<>();'="]+)+$","actual":"ns=3;s=Oxigen","message":"invalid input"},
        {"attribute":"pattern","property":"devices.0.attributes.3.object_id","expected":"^([^<>();'="]+)+$","actual":"ns=3;s=Temperature","message":"invalid input"},
        {"attribute":"pattern","property":"devices.0.attributes.2.object_id","expected":"^([^<>();'="]+)+$","actual":"ns=3;s=EngineStopped","message":"invalid input"},
        {"attribute":"pattern","property":"devices.0.attributes.1.object_id","expected":"^([^<>();'="]+)+$","actual":"ns=3;s=Acceleration","message":"invalid input"},
        {"attribute":"pattern","property":"devices.0.attributes.0.object_id","expected":"^([^<>();'="]+)+$","actual":"ns=3;s=EngineBrake","message":"invalid input"},
        {"attribute":"pattern","property":"devices.0.lazy.0.object_id","expected":"^([^<>();'="]+)+$","actual":"ns=3;s=Speed","message":"invalid input"}
    ]
}
```

Then, If I run the Agent in Node.js, I get the same error:

> `{"name":"WRONG_SYNTAX","message":"Wrong syntax in request: Errors found validating request."}`

If I try to use `iotagent4fiware/iotagent-opcua:latest`, which should be the same of running the cloned repository in Node.js, it seems to ignore the `endpointUrl` present in the  `configuration.properties` file, and it try to connect always to `opc.tcp://iotcarsrv:5001/UA/CarServer`.
Of course, connection fails...

I'm pretty confused from that behaviors, and I can't add anything to the IoTAgent.

Comment: The latest OPC-UA IoT Agent is [1.4.3](https://github.com/Engineering-Research-and-Development/iotagent-opcua/releases/tag/v1.4.3) not 1.3.4. There was a templating fix to do with [forbidden characters](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/forbidden_characters.html#general-restrictions) which was fixed [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/pull/920)

Comment: I'm not sure which is the first version of the OPC-UA IoT Agent that contains the fix, but I suspect that it is later than 1.3.4.  It is possible that you need to just need to upgrade to 1.4.3

Comment: As wrote, if I use the latest versione it seams to ignore the endpoint and fails the connection to an external server, there is also a commit on GitHub about 1.3.4 https://github.com/Engineering-Research-and-Development/iotagent-opcua/commit/c71ea2419346a11f6473fe0cde21811bcf03cb4e

Comment: I just realized that the latest version from Docker Hub is the 1.4.0. The 1.4.3 present on GitHub has not been built, so now I understand the different behavior between running the code on local Node.js, and running from the latest image of Docker Hub.

Comment: @JasonFox Looking for `relaxTemplateValidation` in the code, I found the setting `"relaxTemplateValidation": true` inside the `config.json` file.
Since I was using the empty `config.json` to test the mapping tool, this setting was missing.
Adding the setting `"relaxTemplateValidation": true` seams to solve the syntax issue.  But I still can't add a device, now I get the following error:

`{"name":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"Request error connecting to the Context Broker: 400"}`

Comment: Superficially it looks like your network comms within your docker compose is incorrect somehow, but that comment is insufficient to diagnose further. Your best bet is to increase the debug in the context broker and the IoT Agent and post the logs into your question above: this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRqJsywi9e8) describes the steps.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make it work, looking at another [issue on the repository](https://github.com/Engineering-Research-and-Development/iotagent-opcua/issues/67#issuecomment-1036429120).
Using "*" instead of "=", and ":" instead of ";", I've overcome the syntax issue.

That syntax was present on the file `testCommands\MultiDeviceTest\add_device_lazy_attrs.json` but is not documented anyware.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this curl to add a new device

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:4001/iot/devices' \
  --header 'fiware-service: opcua_car' \
  --header 'fiware-servicepath: /demo' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-raw '{
    "devices": [
      {
        "device_id": "age03_Car",
        "entity_name": "age03_Car",
        "entity_type": "Device",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "object_id": "ns=3;s=EngineBrake",
            "name": "EngineBrake",
            "type": "Number"
          }, {
            "object_id": "ns=3;s=Acceleration",
            "name": "Acceleration",
            "type": "Number"
          }, {
            "object_id": "ns=3;s=EngineStopped",
            "name": "EngineStopped",
            "type": "Boolean"
          }, {
            "object_id": "ns=3;s=Temperature",
            "name": "Engine_Temperature",
            "type": "Number"
          }, {
            "object_id": "ns=3;s=Oxigen",
            "name": "Engine_Oxigen",
            "type": "Number"
          }, {
            "object_id": "ns=3;s=DataBlocksGlobal_3_dbRfidCntr_3_ID1_3_xBusy",
            "name": "DataBlocksGlobal_3_dbRfidCntr_3_ID1_3_xBusy",
            "type": "String"
          }, {
            "object_id": "ns=3;s=DataBlocksGlobal_3_dbRfidCntr_3_ID1_3_xBusyStatus",
            "name": "DataBlocksGlobal_3_dbRfidCntr_3_ID1_3_xBusyStatus",
            "type": "Boolean"
          }
        ],
        "lazy": [
          {
            "object_id": "ns=3;s=Speed",
            "name": "Speed",
            "type": "Number"
          }, {
            "object_id": "ns=3;s=GPSCoordinates",
            "name": "GPSCoordinates",
            "type": "Number"
          }
        ],
        "commands": [
          {
            "object_id": "ns=3;s=Stop",
            "name": "Stop",
            "type": "command"
          }, {
            "object_id": "ns=3;s=Accelerate",
            "name": "Accelerate",
            "type": "command"
          }, {
            "object_id": "ns=3;s=ActivateSensor",
            "name": "ActivateSensor",
            "type": "command"
          }, {
            "object_id": "ns=3;s=DeactivateSensor",
            "name": "DeactivateSensor",
            "type": "command"
          }, {
            "object_id": "ns=3;s=ToggleSensorActivation",
            "name": "ToggleSensorActivation",
            "type": "command"
          }, {
            "object_id": "ns=3;s=LaunchMissiles",
            "name": "LaunchMissiles",
            "type": "command"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: That is the same syntax that is present in the "testCommands/add_device_NGSIv2.json" and result in the same errof of course:

`{"name":"WRONG_SYNTAX","message":"Wrong syntax in request: Errors found validating request."}`